# Rails to symbol problems? Error: undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Background info: A Deal has many coupons (@freeDeals contains all those coupons) and a coupon belongs_to a Deal.

Controller:

```
 @freeCoupons = Coupon.where(discount: 100).order("created_at DESC").page(params[:page])
 @deals = Deal.all
```

This code below works exactly like I want and finds the title for the deal (hard coded in the 2 for testing purposes)

```
<% @freeCoupons.each do |f| %>
      <%= @deals[2][:title] %>

 <% end %>
```

But when I switch it over to trying to find the title of the deal based on the coupons association through f.deal_id

```
<% @freeCoupons.each do |f| %>
      <%= @deals[f.deal_id][:title] %>

<% end %>
```

It gives me this error "undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass". Not sure what I'm missing here. Is it a symbol problem that I'm missing? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Is each `Coupon` record guaranteed to have a `deal_id` that points to an existing `Deal`?

Comment: @lurker Correct. Each coupon will have a deal_id number associated to it. Similar to how a post will have a blog_id

Comment: On the surface, it appears this should work fine. However, perhaps one of your assumptions is not true? You'd need to test that out by checking inside your `@freeCoupons.each` loop explicitly for each `f` that `f.deal_id` is valid, and then that `@deals[f.deal_id]` is valid. You didn't say what line of code the error is pointing to, but I assume it's `@deals[f.deal_id][:title]`, so either `@deals` would have to be `nil`, or `@deals[f.deal_id]` would have to be `nil` to get that error. You'll need to do some debugging to find it.

Comment: Logan Serman has provided the best possible answer. Always use your relationships. From your question it's clear that you've established a `belongs_to` relationship from `Coupon` to `Deal`, so you can call `coupon.deal.title` to get the coupon's deal's title.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your Coupon model do

`belongs_to :deal`

Then in your controller, include the deals using `includes` - this will ensure you don't make an N+1 query:

```
@free_coupons = Coupon.includes(:deal).where(discount: 100).order("created_at DESC").page(params[:page])
```

Now in your view, you can simply call the `deal` method on a `Coupon` instance:

```
@free_coupons.each do |f|
  <%= f.deal.title %>
end
```

Comment: OP: This is by far the best answer. The Rails way has you using the relationship between models to get related data.

Answer (score 1):

`deal_id` is the id in the database, and it is NOT the index in the array. `deal_id` can be much bigger that the number of elements. Than you get a `nil`, and your error when you try to access the `title`

You find a Object by ID with

```
Deal.find(f.deal_id)
```

Comment: This is the wrong direction to take. You're solving his problem on the surface, but not fixing the larger problem of why he isn't using his relationships.

Comment: I disagree. You need learn to walk before you can run. The user need to know why this error occurred, even when he later use another approach.

Comment: Thanks! Nice to see how it should've been done even though Logan's answer is the more proper way to do it like Richard said. I thought of this solution originally, but was trying to avoid doing a find query in the view since that breaks the mvc way from what I understand.